# Linear Plot and Equation Wrong with only two data points

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

Help please. Excel 2007. Trying to create linear graph with only two data points and plot and equation are in error. Using Insert>Scatter>Scatter with Straight Line.

```
x   y
0   10
5   20
```

[image: Wrong plot or equation]

But if rearrange the data, get the correct plot and equation below. Something's not right. Help please.

```
x   y
0   5
10  20
```

[image: As it should be]

Have also tried increasing the precision of the data to 15 decimal digits, still same results. But if use more than 2 data points, all is OK.

Comment: Excel has plotted your first range by rows, not by columns.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the data which the chart is based is selected wrongly. Right click the chart, choose *select data*. Click *edit* in legend entry, then another window will pop up. In that window, select the 0-5 column as the series name and the 10-20 column as the series values. Click OK everywhere and it should work.